# How Asta is able to go through portals without dissolving them?

Tags: black-clover

During several fights in Black Clover, Asta was teleporting through portals created by Finral for surprise strikes. Yet, during attack on capital city earlier, it was shown that his sword is dissipating portals.

How it is possible for him to use portals while holding materialized sword?

Comment: raw speculation: the sword doesn't touch the edges of the portals?

Comment: When he threw sword into middle of portal during defending the capital, sword didn't touched edges as well.